# Display selected option for an associated collection_select field from within a nested_form_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are my Associations:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agencies_hotline_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotline_services, through: :agencies_hotline_services 
end

#rich join table between agencies and hotline_services
class AgenciesHotlineService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotline_service
  belongs_to :agency
end

class HotlineService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotline_service_category
  has_many :agencies_hotline_services
  has_many :agencies, through: :agencies_hotline_services
end

class HotlineServiceCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotline_services
end
```

When a user is creating a new `agency`, I utilize the [nested_form_fields](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields) gem so that the user can dynamically add new `hotline_services` for an `agency`:

[image: Button which dynamically adds a nested_field to create an agencies_hotline_services record]

And when the **Add a Service this Agency Provides** button is clicked:

[image: after clicked].

When the user selects the `hotline_service_category` from that select box, an ajax request is called which then updates the `hotline_service` selection to only those `hotline_services` associated with that selected `hotline_service_category`:

[image: ajax request upon service_category selection updates services selection]

This all works wonderfully for when creating a *new* `agency`.  Where I am running into trouble is when I want to **edit** an existing `agency`:

[image: editing agency]

The nested_fields portion of the `agency` form properly shows the existing selected options per each of the agency's associated `hotline_services`.  However, the form *does not* show the associated `hotline_service_category` option selection per each `hotline_service`. I do want to show the existing selected option for `hotline_service_category`.

**Note**: The `hotline_service_category` is not saved in the rich join table.  It is grabbed by going through the associated `hotline_service`.

So somehow with my collection select for the `hotline_service_category`, I want to say: Hey, look at the selected `hotline_service` option located in the collection_select below this one, grab the associated `hotline_service_category`, and display that as the selected option for the `hotline_service_category`.

Here is the relevant code from the `_form.html.erb` for an `agency`:

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :agencies_hotline_services do |ff| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
      <%= label_tag "Service Category" %>
      <%= collection_select(:hotline_service_category_id, nil, HotlineServiceCategory.all, :id, :description, {prompt: '-Select-'}, class: "form-control", id: "new_edit_hotline_service_category_selection") %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
      <%= ff.label "Service Provided" %>
      <%= ff.collection_select(:hotline_service_id, HotlineService.all, :id, :description, {}, class: "form-control hotline_service_selection") %>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <br>
      <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link "Remove", class: "btn btn-small btn-danger "%>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= f.add_nested_fields_link :agencies_hotline_services, "Add a Service this Agency Provides", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hotline_service_category` is not stored in the db (its not part of the attributes that the nested form "knows") and thats why its not setting it automatically.

`HotlineService belongs_to :hotline_service_category` so `hotline_service` will have a field in the db of `hotline_service_category_id`

so what you can do is check if there is `hotline_service` and in case its exists, take the `hotline_service_category_id` and set the `collection_select` selected value to the `hotline_service_category_id`

so what you need to do is adding `selected` value like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:hotline_service_category_id, .... {selected: ID} ) %>
```

You can get the nested object like this: `ff.object` 
which is of type `agencies_hotline_services`.
then you can get the category id by using: `ff.object.hotline_service.hotline_service_category_id`

you should use `try` to avoid nil errors. so:

```
ff.object.try(:hotline_service).try(:hotline_service_category_id)
```

BUT You should first check if the record is not new, because if its new, you don't set a selected value. you can do it by checking:

```
ff.object.new_record?
```

so lets combine everything, and you will get:

```
!ff.object.new_record? && ff.object.try(:hotline_service).try(:hotline_service_category_id) ? {} : {selected: ff.object.try(:hotline_service).try(:hotline_service_category_id) }
```

add this to your `collection_select` field, and it should set the value.

a more cleaner way will be to use some other variable to store it so the collection select won't be so long.

```
<% selected_value = ff.object.try(:hotline_service).try(:hotline_service_category_id) if !ff.object.new_record? %>
```

and then just add:

```
selected_value ? {} : {selected: selected_value }
```

*** I'm not sure that the "selected: ID" is the way to set the selected value, maybe you need the name of the category or the position of the category in the collection, but I'm sure you'll manage to find it yourself.

**EDIT:**

I used enum for the collection_select.
i could set the selected value of the collection by using the string that it shows. (in my case: the name of the model)
so you can try:

```
ff.object.try(:hotline_service).try(:hotline_service_category).try(:description)
```

or whatever the name of the field that contains the category text that is shown.